# React component loading before save has finished

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a site where the user can navigate by using a menu system.  I have my save function firing on the componentWillUnmount.  One page in particular allows a user to set a field where they can define a number.  The next page generates a bunch of text fields corresponding to that number.  The problem is, the second page loads before the first page has finished saving.  So if page 1 initially has a value of 1 and I change it to 2, the second page will display 1 text field initially, forcing me to refresh the page to see the correct data.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated!

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Saving on unmount seems like an unnatural thing to do as I presume your save is asynchronous?  Is there any reason you can't save before the component is unloaded?